# Unable to find "Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)" plugin in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, plugins, android-studio-3.0, arcore, sceneform

I am currently trying to use Google's ARCore libraries, particularly sceneform, to render an imported 3D model. I'm trying to use this [guide from google](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/import-assets) to do this.

However, when I go to **File > Settings > Plugins > Browse Repositories** I am unable to find the "Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)" plugin. It simply doesn't show up, as seen here: [No results shown on search "Google Sce"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8hWD.png). I have tried many other variations of the search, it just doesn't seem to appear in the list at all.

I have also tried manually downloading and installing from the [jetbrains page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10698-google-sceneform-tools-beta-), but when I try to install from disk I get the error:

> Plugin 'Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)' is incompatible with this installation

I am currently using Android Studio 3.0.1, with Android SDK 24.4.1. My only other idea is that there is a setting somewhere which dictates what plugins show up, but I have not found anything about that online. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I found this plugin...
You use Android Studio 3.1 or higher?

Comment: Yes, I added my version as an edit.

Comment: Your version is not 3.1 or higher. Try to update version to 3.1 or higher?

Comment: Ah, I completely misread the version number. I will try updating, thanks!

Comment: Looks like that was the issue! I can't believe I got so lost in trying crazy solutions I forgot to just update. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your Android Studio version and upgrade.

It should be at least 3.1